# How do I use line-height correctly?

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation menu 100% width fixed to the top of the page.

```
#nav {

height: 50px;

}
```

I've used line-height to put text in center of the nav before but it's not working when I do this..

```
#nav ul li a {

line-height: 50px;
 }
```

It is appearing half way off the bottom of the nav

Comment: @HunterTurner my bad took it out while messing around with it..back in now see edit

Comment: Post a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, You seem to have missed the fact that browsers have some inbuilt styles for the elements like `<ul>` etc.

And that margin for the `<ul>` is pushing the whole menu down.

Try "normalizing" your css by including

```
ul {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

As shown [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/omdtdagz/).

Comment: thank you, my padding was messing with it too...if thats possible. Fixed now thanks.